# ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and re-redering/domchanges

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I try to find out how I should use ngrx-store in combination with OnPush changedetection strategy.

Let's say I want to set a class of a selected entity in my collection.
If I do something like this:

```
 this.collection = Observable.combineLatest(
      this.store.let(fromStore.getCollection),
      this.store.let(fromStore.getSelected),
      (c, s) => c.map(entity => {return { ...entity, isSelected : s.id === entity.id ? true: 
 false }));
```

or if I set the isSelected property in the reducer it creates a clone of all my entities. With a large collection if I do this:

```
<div *ngFor="let entity of collection| async;let i = index;trackBy:entity?.id"
        [class.selected]="entity.isSelected">
```

it is very slow!

However if I don't subscribe on the selection change like this:

```
this.collection = this.store.let(fromStore.getCollection);
```

change

```
<div ... [class.selected]="entity.isSelected">
```

to

```
<div ...[class.selected]="isSelected(entity.id) | async">
```

and create a function that gets the selected:

```
  public isSelected(id): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.selected && this.selected.find(s => !!s.id === id));
  }
```

It's fast

So it seems that if the stream changes the component that uses the stream will need a lot of time to detect domchanges even if there are none.

Is that correct? That means that you have to be very aware of what you change in the store and what you should do in your components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OnPush` strategy has nothing to do with a component's template expressions. It tells Angular that all of the component's `@Input()` bindings are immutable, and the component's children are dependent.

When Angular does change detection and reaches a component with `OnPush` it will compare the current input values with the previous input values. If all those inputs are still *equal* then detection *stops* at that component. None of it's children will be checked.

When Angular *stops* because of `OnPush` the view for a component and it's children are not updated. The immutable state of the input bindings implies that the view has not changed.

If you have observables that change the internal state of the component for an `OnPush` strategy. You have to call `markForCheck` on `ChangeDetectRef`. This marks that component and all of it's parent's for change detection.

What you describe as delays is just part of the unexpected behavior when you don't use `OnPush` correctly.

Here's a good article on change detection in Angular:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

**UPDATED**:

`OnPush` strategy effects only your component. It does not change the behavior of the ngForOf directive or other components you are using in your template.

> lets say I have 200 items where 2 items are changed. I do an array.map and change the two items...

This is the correct strategy. Rather than modify an existing array and replace/remove items. It's better to yield a new array so that Angular can quickly see that it's changed.

`ngForOf` will iterate all the items in the array *every time* it has to do change detection. For each item it will call the track by function or it will attach a hash value to the items. This is how it tells if items in the array have changed. They can change by being removed or re-ordered.

`ngForOf` maintains a *view* for each item in the array. It will iterate each item and then perform change detection on each view.

`ngForOf` performs the same amount of work if the array reference remains the same, or if it is changed to a new array. It still has to iterate each item. What `ngForOf` can not resolve is when the hash value disappears. It has to tare-down the old view and create a new DOM view for each item.

Let's look at your example:

```
<div *ngFor="let entity of collection| async;let i = index;trackBy:entity?.id" [class.selected]="entity.isSelected">
```

You are using the `trackBy` with this expression `entity?.id`. There are a couple of problems with that expression.

- trackBy must be given a function reference. This was changed from Angular 1 as a requirement for minifying code.
- the expression `entity?` yields `undefined` when the entity value doesn't exist. `ngForOf` can not track `undefined` and will be forced to tare-down and rebuild the DOM for each undefined item.
- `ngForOf` can not track `entity?.id` unless the property `id` is a function. I think this is a property value and `ngForOf` is going to ignore it.
- finally, I think the `entity` variable does not exist in the scope of the ngForOf expression. So the trackBy won't work.

This means that every time you recreate the array the DOM gets rebuilt and that's going to be very slow.

You need to use a valid track by function in your component:

```
 public trackEntity(indx: number, value: any) {
     if('id' in value) {
           return value.id;
     }
     return value || indx;
 }
```

The above will try to track by the entity ID property, but if you have `undefined` items this will fall back to the index offset.

In your template you need to use the above function for the `trackBy`:

```
<div *ngFor="let entity of collection| async;let i = index;trackBy:trackEntity" [class.selected]="entity.isSelected">
```

Notice that there are no `()` braces. The function is being passed by reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using ngrx-store, if the state changes a new state has to be return. So if i'm changing an array of lets say 200 items where 2 items are changed, as far as I understand, I do an array.map, change the two items but as I do a map i also creates a new array so all items are not equal to the ones before the change. Which I guess is good in a Flux architect but not for performance if actions result in returning a clone of an large array

Comment: Angular iterates all the items in an array when it digests a ngForOf directive. It uses the trackBy to see if needs to tare-down a child element or not. I can see that you're doing `trackBy: entity?.id` which is likely the problem. Track by has to be a function. Which yields a comparable value or object reference. I think I'll update my answer to example.

Comment: I tested it and it works fast. Thanks for your explanation!